# Datatables get columns structure automatically with ajax object datasource

Tags: datatables

How could I get columns structure automatically with this kind of datatable? The idea is that there will be different number and order of columns depending of the params that I send to the server using the ajax data source with objects.

(I only need the base names of the columns, I don't need the translated ones)

here is my code simplified:

```
var tableId = 'tableId';
var tableName = jQuery('#' + tableId).DataTable({
    language: dataTablesTexts,
    pagingType: 'full',
    lengthMenu: [
        [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], 
        [5, 10, 25, 50, 'All'],
    ],
    searching: true,
    ordering: true,
    aaSorting: [],
    paging: true,
    select: false,
    info: true,
    responsive: true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/historic/getTasks',
        data: function (d) {
            return $.extend( {}, d, {
                token: localStorage.token,
                params: params
            });
        },
    dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'name',
        title: lang.name
    }, {
        data: 'description',
        title: lang.description
    }, {
        data: 'edit',
        title: ''
    }]
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTables - Dynamic Columns From Ajax Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046139/datatables-dynamic-columns-from-ajax-data-source)

Comment: not really, in this case datasource is relevant (with array method is easy to loop around data and get the names for the columns, but in object source from ajax is different,