# DataTables - set column names dynamically from an ajax request with multiple tables per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

In DataTables is it possible to render column headings (`<thead>` > `<th>` elements) dynamically based on an ajax response? Critically, there are **multiple** tables on the page at the same time, as opposed to other answers where it's just 1 table where the column names change based on the data in the ajax response.

Previously I've used it where the `<table>` HTML is present on page load and contains the column headings, e.g.

```
<table id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Table 1 - Column A</th>
            <th>Table 1 - Column B</th>
            <th>Table 1 - Column C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


<table id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Table 2 - Column A</th>
            <th>Table 2 - Column B</th>
            <th>Table 2 - Column C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In this scenario there are 2 tables with ID's `#table1` and `#table2`. I initialized them as follows:

```
$.each($('table'), function () {
    drawTable($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This takes the ID for each table and calls a custom function I wrote called `drawTable()` and passes the ID as an argument. The `drawTable()` function then initiaizes the DataTable on that element, and handles the ajax request/response, e.g.

```
function drawTable(id) {
        $id = $('#'+id); // Convert string ID to jQuery identifier

        $id.DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            searching: false,
            ajax: {
                data: {
                   table_id: id, // So we know which table ID to obtain data for
                   // ...
                },
                url: '/get-data.json', 
            },
            columns: [
              { "data": "columnA", "name": "columnA" },
              { "data": "columnB", "name": "columnB" },
              { "data": "columnC", "name": "columnC" },
            ],
            // ...
        });
    }
```

This works because in the above example both tables have the same columns in them.

I now have a scenario where one table contains 5 columns and the other 3. The names (as in the text that will appear in the `<th>` elements) are completely different in both cases.

How can I handle this? My thought was that I'd have to make a request to an ajax endpoint to produce an array - defined in `columns:` in the js above. Or to hardcode the array into my js for each table and then somehow determine which array to use based on the ID of the table.

However I'm unsure if this is the right approach or how people have handled this before?

DataTables version is 1.10.18 and jQuery 3.2.1

I had a look at [DataTables - Dynamic Columns From Ajax Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046139/datatables-dynamic-columns-from-ajax-data-source) but this seems different to what I'm doing. Because on this example they have **one table** (with an ID `#example`) and are then rendering column names based on an ajax response. In my application **multiple tables** are visible at the same time, and they all have different column names.

The other avenue I considered was to get rid of the `$.each` code and simply have a separate function per table. But this seems very against [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) because I'd be repeating a lot of the same properties, when it's really just `columns:` that needs to change per table - as far as I can see?

Comment: before loading the table data, you may perform ajax-call to your backend to retrieve column titles/data source/whatever dynamic settings you require